# Why __init__() is not recognizing the attributes when I instantiate a concentre class that inherits from an abstract class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, abstract-class, abstraction

I have created this dummy abstract class and concrete class to recreate my problem.

I have an abstract class (MyBase) and a concrete class (Item) that inherits from the abstract class. I am also using the attributes private from within the abstract class. I will need to create multiple classes that inherits from MyBase, so I decided to make make sure the data types are always correct.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


def CheckFuncInput(a_inputVar, a_inputType):
    if isinstance(a_inputVar, a_inputType):
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError('\nArgument {} is not a/an {}\n'.format(
            a_inputVar, str(a_inputType).split()[1]))

    return None


class MyBase(ABC):

    def __init__(self, param0, param1):
        self.param0 = param0
        self.param1 = param1

    # param0.getter
    @property
    def param0(self):
        return self.__param0

    @param0.setter
    def param0(self, param0):
        CheckFuncInput(param0, float)
        self.__param0 = param0
        return None

    # param1.getter
    @property
    def param1(self):
        return self.__param1

    @param1.setter
    def param1(self, param1):
        CheckFuncInput(param1, float)
        self.__param1 = param1
        return None

    @abstractmethod
    def get_process_design_paremeters(self, input_):
        pass

        return None


class Item(MyBase):

    def __init__(self, param0, param1, extra):
        super().__init__(param0)
        super().__init__(param1)
        self.extra = extra

        return None

    @classmethod
    def NewConstructor(cls, a_list):
        param0 = a_list[0]
        param1 = a_list[1]
        extra = 3.0
        return cls(param0, param1, extra)
    
    def get_process_design_paremeters(self, input_):
        pass

        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylist = [1.0, 2.0]
    item1 = Item.NewConstructor(mylist)
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:84 in <module>
    item1 = Item.NewConstructor(mylist)

  File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:74 in NewConstructor
    return cls(param0, param1, extra)

  File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:62 in __init__
    super().__init__(param0)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param1'
```

I am not sure what the real problem is, but it seems that param0 is not being recognized.
I am using conda python 3.9.12.

I do not understand the problem. I have a very similar file with no issues. There must be a small bug that is screwing me up.

Comment: Shouldn't that line be `super().__init__(param0, param1)` instead given that's how its parent defined `def __init__(self, param0, param1):`? (and remove the next `super().__init__(param1)` as that's the wrong signature also, and unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks. That worked.
Can you please state the solution so I can give you the answer?